# How do I parse arguments out of Javascript with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, parsing, web-scraping

I am using Nokogiri to get a JS string out of a document. The resulting string is as follows:

```
js => "/* &lt;![CDATA[ */\n\tvar _cf_map_init_1234567890=function()\n\t{\n\t\tvar _cf_map=ColdFusion.Map.init('Foo Bar',123.0,456.0,'map',6,null,true,true,false,true,true,true,false,false,true,false,'basic','small',null,'42.814001','-73.981458',null,null,null,[{name: 'Baz\\'s',latitude: 42.814001,longitude: -73.981458,markercolor:'#FF0000',showmarkerwindow:true,markerwindowcontent:'Baz\\'s &lt;br /&gt; 123 Sesame Street  &lt;br /&gt; Schenectady, NY &lt;br /&gt; ',tip: ''}],null,null,false,null,null);\n\t};ColdFusion.Event.registerOnLoad(_cf_map_init_1234567890);\n/* ]]&gt; */"
```

I then use [rkelly-remix](https://github.com/nene/rkelly-remix) to parse the JS.

```
parser = RKelly::Parser.new
ast = parser.parse(js)
```

`ast.to_ecma` results in the following:

```
var _cf_map_init_1234567890 = function() {
  var _cf_map = ColdFusion.Map.init('Foo Bar', 123.0, 456.0, 'map', 6, null, true, true, false, true, true, true, false, false, true, false, 'basic', 'small', null, '42.814001', '-73.981458', null, null, null, [{
    name: 'Baz\'s',
    latitude: 42.814001,
    longitude: -73.981458,
    markercolor: '#FF0000',
    showmarkerwindow: true,
    markerwindowcontent: 'Baz\'s &lt;br /&gt; 123 Sesame Street  &lt;br /&gt; Schenectady, NY &lt;br /&gt; ',
    tip: ''
}], null, null, false, null, null);
};
ColdFusion.Event.registerOnLoad(_cf_map_init_1234567890);
```

All that I really want to get out of this is the value `123 Sesame Street, Schenectady, NY`. But I should be able to handle the string parsing if I can just get the array of arguments (or parameters if that's a better term) passed to `ColdFusion.Map.init`.

When I try to iterate over each node using rkelly's parsed result, I get errors calling `.name` or `.value`, so I'm stuck there.

```
ast.each do |node|
  puts node.name
end

=> NoMethodError: undefined method 'name' for #<RKelly::Nodes::SourceElementsNode:0x007fc375dcdf30>

JSON.parse(ast.to_ecma.to_json)

=> JSON::ParserError: 757: unexpected token at...
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: The "results" you posted are just JavaScript code, not an AST like I assume RKelly would give you, so we can't really do much with that. Please edit your question to include, at a minimum, the code you've written so far and the exact text of the error messages you're getting, as well as the actual AST returned by RKelly.

Comment: Yes @Jordan, I posted the result of calling `ast.to_ecma`. I will try to provide more information.

Comment: The error message tells you that the node you're calling `name` on doesn't have a `name` method. In the example in the rkelly-remix README we see that the author explicitly checks if the `name` method exists before calling it: `node.name   = 'hello' if node.respond_to?(:name) && ...`. You should probably do the same.

Comment: And it's not at all clear what you're trying to do with `JSON.parse(ast.to_ecma.to_json)`. Whatever it is, I'm pretty sure it's not going to help you get those values out of that JavaScript.